# Search во Vue js с перебором массива

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, search, axios

Не могу перебрать массив из объектов и выдать значение name, при использовании npm json-server db.json
Есть 2 метода нужно чтобы они работали вместе в одном li и searchFilter() как-то кривовато со всем этим работает

Вот скрины с консоли

[image: вот что выводиться в консоли]

db.json выглядит так

```
{
  "todos": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Михаил Жванецкий"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Виктор Цой"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Петр Гланц"
    }
  ]
}
```

App.vue выглядит так

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>FindBase</h1>
    <input type="text" v-model="todoName" @keyup.enter="addTodo" placeholder="Add Something" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Find" v-model="search" />
    <ul>
      <li v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id">{{todo.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

const baseURL = "http://localhost:3000/todos";

export default {
  name: "app",
  data() {
    return {
      todos: [],
      todoName: "",
      search: "",
    };
  },
  watch: {
    searchKeyword() {
      if (!this.keyword) return;
      this.debounceName();
    },
  },
  async created() {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(baseURL);

      this.todos = res.data;
      console.log(this.todos);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    searchFilter() {
      return this.todos.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
        return arrayItem.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search !== -1);
      });
    },
  },
  methods: {
    async addTodo() {
      const res = await axios.post(baseURL, { name: this.todoName });
      this.todos = [...this.todos, res.data];

      this.todoName = "";
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6c5ce7;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  color: #a29bfe;
}

input {
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Comment: А если убрать условие v-if="search !== true" ? И searchFilter - нигде не используется , хотя думаю должно быть как то так  v-for="todo in searchFilter "

Comment: Оно работает без v-if, если добавить searchFilter в v-for то список не будет отображаться.

Comment: Убери условие и Замени return arrayItem.toLowerCase().filter(this.indexOf(this.search) !== -1);

Comment: Убрал условие и поправил второй return но также ничего не поменялось

Comment: И searchFilter в цикле вместо todos?

Comment: todos и searchFilter должны работать вместе, проблема с объединением методов в одном li.

Comment: Главный вопрос я не знаю как при таком обстоятельстве перебрать массив с объектами и вытащить то что будет в поиске